# retrieving values from 3 one-to-one relationship table (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, relational-database, sqlplus

[image]
Each `Student` and `Teacher` have their own `UNIQUE` `UserID`
Is it possible to retrieve the values from the three tables at once? 
such that: it will display the `UserID` owned by each `Student` or `Teacher`?
I've tried the following query, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT u.UserID, StudentID, TeacherID  
FROM User u  
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Student, Teacher) ss  
ON u.UserID = ss.UserID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this way:

```
SELECT u.UserID, S.StudentID, T.TeacherID  
from User U
left join Student S on S.UserID = u.UserID  
left join Teacher T on T.UserID = U.UserID
```